# Unlike Windows Registry Editor is there any Registry editor in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I have used Windows registry editor to edit certain functions and to delete the unwanted files in Windows.
So is there any Registry editor in Ubuntu to edit the files in Ubuntu?
Except using Wine !

Comment: Can you be more specific about which files you wish to delete or edit?

Comment: Mainly installed files and many OS Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no registry in Linux. You should read something about system (there is really good book - you can buy printed version or download ebook for free: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/13.07/TLCL-13.07.pdf/download)
2. You can find config files in /etc.
3. Binary files are in /usr/bin, but you should use rather package-manager (like CLI apt-get or GUI synaptic).

Answer (score 1):

The "registry" editor is call `dconf-editor` and you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Example image:

[image]

But I am in doubt about this:

> and to delete the unwanted files in Windows

A registry editor does NOT delete files. It is used to change settings.

Comment: If any files installed in windows. Sometimes it will get stored in Registry Editor. Hence I'll delete those files and we can able to turn off certain functions in which we do not want.

Comment: After installing dconf-editor, Am getting this.** (dconf-editor:3932): WARNING **: dconf-schema.vala:330: Unknown property on <schema>, extends

** (dconf-editor:3932): WARNING **: dconf-schema.vala:330: Unknown property on <schema>, extends

Comment: Warning are not important; just means there is a property with an unexpected value. It'll get solved when someone updates it. Regarding the 1st comment: Ubuntu does NOT work like that. Registry is used for settings and settings only. Programs can not store a "cache" in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, unlike windows, does not have registry entries. instead is relying on text files placed in the `/etc/` directory for configuration and settings.

There are some tools to change those files in GUI environment like `dconf-editor`

for getting more information about installed packages on your system and cleaning up your system, `synaptic` is a fantastic tool.

[Synaptic Package Manager Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowton3tzfv27GraGJl6BA&bvm=bv.99261572,d.ZGU)